# If $L$ is a straight line then what is the topology that $L$ inherits as a subspace from $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> If $L$ is a straight line then what is the topology that $L$ inherits as a subspace from $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ and as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ .

I know that the basis of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ is $(a, b] \times (a, b) $ and so the basis of $(\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R} ) \cap L$ is $((a, b] \times (a, b) ) \cap L$.

I know that the basis of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ is $(a, b] \times (a, b] $ and so the basis of $(\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R} ) \cap L$ is $((a, b] \times (a, b]) \cap L$.

Am I on the right track? I need some hints from here. (not the full answer)

Comment: No I was not really looking for a complete answer. I just want to know how would you progress after coming up-to this? I need some hints(along with the reason as to why you are thinking of the hints)  which would help me to think rather than going through the solution.